# How to do a if-else operation in ksh command from parsing

Tags: shell, ksh, daemon

I am trying to find the path of a daemon using `which` command by the following in a ksh shell script

But if the daemon is not present it gives a warning in the format..

`no DaemonName .....bla bla bla`

But since I cannot display that directly, I currently do this

```
tmp=`which daemonName`
tmp2=`which daemonName | grep "no DaemonName"`
if [[ "$tmp2" != "" ]]
tmp=wrong name
```

How can I do the same in a simple single line?

What I really want is that if the daemon is not there, It should give a default string, while if present it should give the `which` commands output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the tmp variable like you want it:

```
tmp=$(which daemonName) || tmp="wrong name"
```

Edit: One issue with this suggestion is the `which` command behavior isn't standardized, as the AIX odd implementation demonstrates.

As you use `ksh`, a simple workaround is to substitute the `which` command by the `whence` builtin:

```
tmp=$(whence -f daemonName) || tmp="wrong name"
```

Comment: I would say your which command is broken. Please tell the OS, "ksh" and "which" versions you use.

Comment: OS is AIX 6.2 :P thats all I know :D

Answer (score 0):

`which` doesn't report that error on my distribution, but this will probably work for you:

```
tmp=`which daemonName 2> /dev/null`
...
```

Basically, you're just throwing away any error messages that occur.

Comment: But that would give me a blank tmp variable

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
tmp=$(which dawmonName 2>/dev/null)
: ${tmp:=wrong name}
echo "$tmp"
```

The `:=` part *assigns* the text if the variable is null or unset. The `:` command does nothing except it allows parameter expansion or its arguments.